# Kubuntu 20.10, after installing Snap app, no position in menu

Tags: kubuntu, snap

After installing snap apps (MS Visual Code, Spotify, Intellij IDEA, Chromium), i don't have any extra positions in main menu.
I need to type full name of an app ('chromium' for example, to see 'Run chromium' or 'intellij-idea-community' to run Idea).
Why? Why there is no integration between Snap and Kubuntu ? is it possible to turn it on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so according to Internet, the problem is my default shell - ZSH. (strangely it affects Plasma as well...)

i could see links to my apps:

> ls -l /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications

but this variable was not pointing there:

> echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
> /usr/share/plasma:/usr/local/share:/usr/share

i had to edit **/etc/zsh/zprofile** and add at the end of that file:

> emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh'

which adds snap directories to $XDG_DATA_DIRS